# How to set the maximum deploymeny target on Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Inside my info.plist file I select Deployment target as 12.0 and 12.0 is the last option.so I need to know How to set the maximum target to 12.3
[image]

when I edit the info.plist to xml view then its showing

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>12.0</string>
```

how how to set the maximum OS Version?

Comment: people can install from 11.0 to 12.3

Comment: Native iOS supported versions upto  iOS 12.1 with Xcode 10.1(stable) until now, then how should '12.3'.